# Create an Acumatica Data Provider for fixed-field length .txt

Tags: acumatica

I have to create a new data provider or use one of Acumatica data providers to process a fixed-field length .txt file every day. I need to do an Import scenario, but I can't get the Data Provider for this .txt file to work. Is there any way that I can either create one or use one of the predefined data providers in Acumatica?

I have tried to modify the ACH Data provider but I could not make it work. Attached is an example of that file.

Comment: There is nothing attached... add your attachment to the question body.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry for not answering before, The issue is that Acumatica does not have a Data Provider for a fixed field length .txt file, and they dont, so the solution seems to be as of right now to convert the file to CSV ( I tried Macros in Excel but the files are too big).

the image is on this link. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZTML.jpg.